Plots don't show after using plot() function but only gives an output [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x273b82d3f50>]
I defined a function called efficient_frontier and returned an axes. However, when I use this axes to add new features and then plot it, I only get an output [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x273b82d3f50>] but the plotting graph does not show up. I'm using Python 3.11 and I places %matplotlib inline and import matplotlib.pyplot as plt before.
I've searched many questions and answers but don't get what I want.
r_msr and vol_msr just get returns and volatility for a maximum sharpe ratio portfolio.
The whole code looks like this below:
import akshare as ak
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def get_ind_returns(symbol_list,start_date,end_date):
    """
    Using the akshare toolkit to obtain industry-level stock returns
    Parameters:
        symbol_list:a list of industry names to enter
        start_date: the starting date for the period
        end_date: the ending date for the period
    Returns:
        a dataframe consisting of all the stock indexes of industries as columns
    """
    stock_board_industry_index=ak.stock_board_industry_index_ths(symbol=symbol_list[0] , start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)["日期"].to_frame()
    for i in range(len(symbol_list)):
        stock_board_industry_index_pct=ak.stock_board_industry_index_ths(symbol=symbol_list[i] , start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)["收盘价"].pct_change()
        stock_board_industry_index.insert(i+1,symbol_list[i],stock_board_industry_index_pct,True)
    stock_board_industry_index.index=pd.to_datetime(stock_board_industry_index['日期'],format='%Y%m%d')
    stock_board_industry_index.drop("日期",axis=1,inplace=True)
    return stock_board_industry_index
def annualized_returns(returns,periods_per_year):
    """
    Annualizes a set of returns
    Parameters:
        returns_series:a return series
        periods_per_year: the number of periods counted in a year(365 if counted daily,and 12 if counted monthly)
    Returns:
        annualized_return
    """
    compound_growth_rate=(1+returns).prod()
    n_of_periods=returns.shape[0]
    annalized_return=(compound_growth_rate**(periods_per_year/n_of_periods)-1)
    return annalized_return
def portfolio_return(weights,returns):
    """
    weights->Returns
    """
    return weights.T @ returns
def portfolio_vol(weights,cov_matrix):
    """
    Weights->Volatility
    """
    return (weights.T @ cov_matrix @ weights)**0.5
def minimize_vol_weight(target_return,er,cov):
    """
    get the weight with minimized volatility for a given target return
    
    Parameters:
        target_return: the target return for a portfolio
        er:the expected return for multiple assets
        cov:the covariance matrix for multiple assets
    Returns the weight after minimizing the volatility
    """
    n=er.shape[0]
    initial_guess=np.repeat(1/n,n)
    bounds=((0,1),)*n
    return_is_target={
        'type':'eq',
        'args':(er,),
        'fun':lambda weights,er:target_return-portfolio_return(weights, er)
        }
    weights_sum_to_1={
        'type':'eq',
        'fun':lambda weights:np.sum(weights)-1
        }
    minimize_vol_weight=minimize(portfolio_vol,initial_guess,args=(cov,)
                          ,method="SLSQP",bounds=bounds,
                          constraints=([return_is_target,weights_sum_to_1]),
                          options={'disp':False}
                          )
    return minimize_vol_weight.x
def optimal_weights(er,cov,n_points):
    """
    get a list of weights for a set of target returns by volatility minimizer


    Parameters:
        er:the expected return for multiple assets
        cov:the covariance matrix for multiple assets
        n_points: number of points to plot
    Returns a list of optimal weights for multiple assets
    """
    target_returns=np.linspace(er.min(),er.max(),n_points)
    optimal_weights=[minimize_vol_weight(target_return, er, cov) for target_return in target_returns]
    return optimal_weights
def efficient_frontier(er,cov,n_points,style=".-"):
    """
    Plots the multi-asset efficient frontier 
    
    Parameters:
        er:the expected return for multiple assets
        cov:the covariance matrix for multiple assets
        n_points: number of points to plot
        style: ways to plot the graph
    Returns the data frame of the efficient frontier
    """
    weights=optimal_weights(er,cov,n_points)
    rets=[portfolio_return(w ,er) for w in weights]
    vols=[portfolio_vol(w, cov) for w in weights]
    efficient_frontier=pd.DataFrame({'Weights':weights,'R':rets,"Vol":vols})
    return efficient_frontier.plot.line(x="Vol", y="R", style=style)
def msr_weight(er,cov,riskfree_rate):
    """
    get the weight with maximum sharpe ratio
    
    Parameters:
        er:the expected return for multiple assets
        cov:the covariance matrix for multiple assets
        riskfree_rate: market riskfree rate
    Returns the weight with maximum sharpe ratio
    """
    n=er.shape[0]
    initial_guess=np.repeat(1/n,n)
    bounds=((0,1),)*n
    weights_sum_to_1={
        'type':'eq',
        'fun':lambda weights:np.sum(weights)-1
        }
    negative_max_sharpe_ratio= lambda weights,riskfree_rate,er,cov: -(portfolio_return(weights, er)-riskfree_rate)/portfolio_vol(weights, cov)
    msr_weight=minimize(negative_max_sharpe_ratio,initial_guess,args=(riskfree_rate,er,cov,)
                          ,method="SLSQP",bounds=bounds,
                          constraints=(weights_sum_to_1),
                          options={'disp':False}
                          )
    return msr_weight.x

symbol_list=['半导体及元件','房地产开发','消费电子','油气开采及服务','银行']
ind=get_ind_returns(symbol_list, '20150101', '20240108')
er=annualized_returns(ind["2010":"2024"], 365)
cov=ind.cov()
rf=0.03
w_msr=erk.msr_weight(er, cov,rf)
ax=efficient_frontier(er, cov, 20)
ax.set_xlim(left=0)
r_msr=portfolio_return(w_msr,er)
vol_msr=portfolio_vol(w_msr, cov)
##Plot cml
cml_x=[0,vol_msr]
cml_y=[rf, r_msr]
ax.plot(cml_x,cml_y,color='green',marker='o',linestyle='dashed',linewidth=2,markersize=12)
plt.show()


Welcome to SO, it is not possible to reproduce your problem as variable such erk or er are not defined. Please read [mcve] and update you post accordingly.

Sorry, I've provided additional codes and editted some code that may cause confusion.

Are you using a Jupyter notebook? Where do you split your cells?

I'm using spyder actually.

@ChenLIU The %matplotlib inline is meant for Jupyter notebooks and isn't needed in spyder. But the output you're seeing is something that is normally shown in a Jupyter notebook, so I'm not sure how you're running your code.

Yes, the thing is that if I run the last codes one by one, I cannot get the desired result. If I run them in a whole, it works well.

Here is how to do this:
import akshare as ak
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def get_historical_data(symbol_list, start_date, end_date):
    data = {}
    for symbol in symbol_list:
        df = ak.stock_zh_a_hist(symbol=symbol, period='daily', start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, adjust="qfq")
        if df.empty:
            print(f"No data found for symbol {symbol}")
            continue
        if '日期' in df.columns:
            df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['日期'])
        elif 'date' in df.columns:
            df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
        else:
            raise KeyError(f"Date column not found in the data for symbol {symbol}")
        
        df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
        df = df['收盘' if '收盘' in df.columns else 'close']
        data[symbol] = df
    combined_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return combined_data

def annualized_returns(price_data, days_per_year):
    returns = price_data.pct_change().mean() * days_per_year
    return returns

def annualized_covariance(price_data, days_per_year):
    returns = price_data.pct_change()
    cov_matrix = returns.cov() * days_per_year
    return cov_matrix

def portfolio_return(weights, returns):
    return np.dot(weights, returns)

def portfolio_vol(weights, cov_matrix):
    return np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights)))

def min_variance(weights, cov_matrix):
    return portfolio_vol(weights, cov_matrix)

def optimal_weights(returns, cov_matrix, n_points):
    target_returns = np.linspace(returns.min(), returns.max(), n_points)
    weights = []

    for target_return in target_returns:
        constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: portfolio_return(x, returns) - target_return},
                       {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
        bounds = tuple((0, 1) for _ in returns)
        result = minimize(min_variance, x0=np.ones(len(returns)) / len(returns), args=cov_matrix,
                          method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
        if result.success:
            weights.append(result.x)
        else:
            weights.append(np.zeros(len(returns)))
    return weights

def efficient_frontier(er, cov, n_points, style=".-"):
    weights = optimal_weights(er, cov, n_points)
    rets = [portfolio_return(w, er) for w in weights]
    vols = [portfolio_vol(w, cov) for w in weights]
    efficient_frontier = pd.DataFrame({'R': rets, "Vol": vols})
    ax = efficient_frontier.plot.line(x="Vol", y="R", style=style)
    return ax

symbol_list = ['000001', '000002', '000004', '000005'] 
start_date = '20150101'
end_date = '20240108'

price_data = get_historical_data(symbol_list, start_date, end_date)

if price_data.empty:
    raise ValueError("No data available for the provided symbols and date range.")

er = annualized_returns(price_data, 365)
cov = annualized_covariance(price_data, 365)

ax = efficient_frontier(er, cov, 20)
ax.set_xlim(left=0)

w_msr = np.ones(len(symbol_list)) / len(symbol_list) 
r_msr = portfolio_return(w_msr, er)
vol_msr = portfolio_vol(w_msr, cov)

rf = 0.03  
cml_x = [0, vol_msr]
cml_y = [rf, r_msr]
ax.plot(cml_x, cml_y, color='green', marker='o', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, markersize=12)

plt.show()

which gives


Thanks a lot. I mind that you changed some of the codings. But can you tell me what is wrong in my code that causes this problem?

hah, I found out that if I run all the code in the last few rows, I got the expected plotting graph. amazing!
